# Thread conflict in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I writed the following code in C#:

```
private void myEnqThread()
        {
            Bitmap temp = null;
            temp = getScreen();
            if(temp!=null)
                queueScreen.Enqueue(temp);
        }

        private Bitmap getScreen(){
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapDesktop;
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics;
            System.IntPtr hWndForeground;// = System.IntPtr.Zero;

            RECT rect = new RECT();
            bitmapDesktop = null;
            graphics = null;
            hWndForeground = System.IntPtr.Zero;

            bitmapDesktop = new Bitmap
            (
                System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
            );

            graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmapDesktop);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
            hWndForeground = GetForegroundWindow();
            GetWindowRect(hWndForeground, out rect);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
            return bitmapDesktop;
        }
```

Can exists more then one threads that executed the method myEnqThread()
For example:

```
Thread oThreadEnqueue = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myEnqThread));
oThreadEnqueue.Start();
Thread oThreadEnqueue2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myEnqThread));
oThreadEnqueue2.Start();
```

I obtain the error:

```
ArgumentException not managed.
```

The error is shown in the image below:

[image]

I suppose that this happens only when more then one thread try to access to that operation, because when I tryed the same code using only one thread theare are no problem.

What can I do for solving this problem? Can I lock the resource?

**EDIT:**

After changes suggested by @Oscar I have obtain [image: this] error

Comment: You shouldn't be addressing UI elements from any thread other that the UI thread.

Comment: ArgumentException is saying the parameter is not valid. Is it possible this method is being called when the screen is not drawn and the bounds values are not defined? When the exception is thrown look at the values of the width and height in the debugger and see if they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'll need to create a lock before calling

```
graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
```

I would recommed too calling Dispose() on all the IDisposbale instances like Graphics and Bitmap in your code in a finally block.

EDIT: Just modified your code. It's not tested, so be careful.

```
public class MyClass{

private static readonly Object objLock = new Object();
private void myEnqThread()
        {
            Bitmap temp = null;
            temp = getScreen();
            if(temp!=null)
                queueScreen.Enqueue(temp);
        }

        private Bitmap getScreen(){
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapDesktop;
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics;
            System.IntPtr hWndForeground;// = System.IntPtr.Zero;

            RECT rect = new RECT();
            bitmapDesktop = null;
            graphics = null;
            hWndForeground = System.IntPtr.Zero;
            lock(objLock){
                bitmapDesktop = new Bitmap
                (
                        System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                    System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
                );

                graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmapDesktop);
                hWndForeground = GetForegroundWindow();
                GetWindowRect(hWndForeground, out rect);
                graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
                return bitmapDesktop;
            }
        }
```

}

Feel free to move the lock, maybe to the very begin of your method if necessary.

Comment: Thank you @Oscar , but how to use the lock in this case?

Comment: A simple lock would consist of `static object screenLock;` at class level, then `lock(screenLock) {...}` around the code to be locked.  Of course, this could possibly cause deadlocks since it doesn't timeout when acquiring the lock.

Comment: Can you modify my code using lock? I have understand how to lock a method.

Comment: @Oscar, I have tried your code but i obtain this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5dnyz6re20zygf/argumentException2.JPG

Comment: Sorry, can't reach dropbox from my current location :-(

Comment: Verify that System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Widthand System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height has value when constr5ucting bitmapDesktop object as sugested.